# Plot the same data on different timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

im trying to get the ema value of 4 hours rsi in different timeframes, but its returning different data in 4h timeframe and daily for example.

OBS: its working fine on intraday timeframes.

```html
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © jeckwilke

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © jeckwilke

//@version=5
indicator("My script")
rsi = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, str.tostring("240"), ta.rsi(close,14), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
rsiMa = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", ta.ema(rsi, 7))

plot(rsiMa[1])
plot(rsiMa[2], color = color.purple)
```

[4 Hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26i0S.png)

[Daily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hT1c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `request.security()` your chart time has to be **equal** or **lower** the timeframe you put into `request.*()`.

To compensate this problem you need to use `request.security.lower_tf()` instead. In this case your chart time has to be **equal** or **higher** than the timeframe you put into `request.*()`.

You can read about using other timeframes [HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering!.
Can you explain why when i use the ta.rsi inside the request.security it returns the same data in each timeframe, even if its higher than the requested timeframe?

rsi= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", ta.rsi(close, 14))
plot(rsi)

Comment: @EduardoMoreira My answer provided a [LINK](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html) in it all will be explained. The part which you were asking is within [request.seucrity_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-security-lower-tf)